# How to populate the state after an action call in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to populate the state after calling an action which retrieves the data of an single object. I want to store this data in the state directly.

```
useEffect(() => {
        getProduct(id);
    }, [getProduct]);

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
```

I tried to store like this:

```
const ProductEdit = ({getProduct, updateProduct, id, products}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getProduct(id);
    }, [getProduct]);

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        quantity: '',
        price: '',
        description: '',
        category: '',
        isImportant: ''
    });

    const {name, quantity, price, description} = formData;

    products.product && setFormData(products.product);
```

Comment: where is your code doing `products.product && setFormData(products.product)` ?

Comment: inside the function after the useState @ZohaibIjaz

Comment: Why are you setting state variable inside render?

Comment: Why don't you share some more code to give us better understanding

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I edited the code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `useEffect` hook to set the state variable

```js
const ProductEdit = ({getProduct, updateProduct, id, products}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getProduct(id);
    }, [getProduct]);

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        quantity: '',
        price: '',
        description: '',
        category: '',
        isImportant: ''
    });

    const {name, quantity, price, description} = formData;
    
    // This hook will only trigger when `products` will change
    useEffect(() => {
      products.product && setFormData(products.product);
    }, [products]);
    
    
}
```